# Weird QByteArray with QDataStream behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

```
QByteArray byteArray;
QDataStream dataStream(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
dataStream << (quint8)22;
dataStream << "test2";
qInfo() << byteArray;
```

Result: `\x16\x00\x00\x00\x06test2\x00`

Why is it using 4 bytes  instead of 1? I explicitly say that I want it to be `unsigned char`. Is there some memory aligning behind the scenes? Can  I turn it off?

EDIT: It seems to happen only when I write `char*` it adds 3 bytes on the beginning from nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\x16\x00\x00\x00\x06test2\x00
```

`\x16` is you uint8.

`\x00\x00\x00\x06` is a fixed size, four byte header of the string length (apparently including the null).

Then your string, followed by a terminating null.

Comment: Indeed, how couldn't I notice it. Probably because qInfo() displays a formatted string instead of just bytes. Thanks!